# Creating a Web App for Generating Images using ML Model (preferably pixel2style2pixel) without NVIDIA GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I am currently developing a web application that allows users to upload a collection of portrait images (10-15 in total) and, in return, generates a series of output images featuring the subject in various scenarios or with specific attributes, such as appearing as an astronaut. The application's primary functionality centers on utilizing a pre-trained machine learning model to process the input images and generate the desired output based on user-defined attributes or contexts.

From my research, it seems like pixel2style2pixel could be a suitable pre-trained model for this purpose. However, I don't have an NVIDIA GPU and need to run the application locally using only my CPU (I know it's not ideal). I tried making `pixel2style2pixel` work on the CPU, but I'm facing issues and it just won't run.

Here's my `requirements.txt` file for my Python project:

```
torch==1.9.0+cpu
torchvision==0.10.0+cpu
Pillow==9.3
-f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
fastai>=2.3.1
ipywidgets
voila
```

But I keep getting CUDA-related errors like:

```
No CUDA runtime is found, using CUDA_HOME='C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA\v11.6'
```

A couple of things to note:

- I've tried installing various CPU-only versions of PyTorch, but it
  still doesn't work.
- My OS is Windows.
- As a developer with a strong background in Java software engineering,
  I have recently embarked on a journey to explore the realm of machine
  learning application development. Despite my limited experience in
  this specific area, my foundational knowledge in software engineering
  allows me to rapidly acquire new skills and effectively connect the
  dots by referring to relevant documentation and dedicating ample time
  to understanding specific subjects.

I'm looking for suggestions on how to achieve this, or if there are any other tools/tech stack that I could use to create this web application without requiring an NVIDIA GPU. Any help is appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your pytorch is fine. What you see is coming from here:

`from torch.utils.cpp_extension import load`
[fused_act.py](https://github.com/eladrich/pixel2style2pixel/blob/5cfff385beb7b95fbce775662b48fcc80081928d/models/stylegan2/op/fused_act.py#L9-L15)

[_find_cuda_home()](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/cce156ac94000e16d4c871bfb9e43939611c9230/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py#L163) outputs that warning of 'No CUDA runtime is found, ...'
But you can just ignore this warning.

More importantly the code tries to compile some cuda files, which is not going to work without cuda and nvidia gpu. I checked the 'load' function calls, and it turns out there are 2 of them in these files:
fused_act.py
upfirdn2d.py
Turns out master of stylegan2 has cpu code for these ops
[fused_act.py](https://github.com/rosinality/stylegan2-pytorch/blob/bef283a1c24087da704d16c30abc8e36e63efa0e/op/fused_act.py#L93-L123)
[upfirdn2d.py](https://github.com/rosinality/stylegan2-pytorch/blob/bef283a1c24087da704d16c30abc8e36e63efa0e/op/upfirdn2d.py#L149-L209)

If you delete or comment out the torch.utils.cpp_extension.load lines and other references to the jit compiled modules, and copy over the cpu code from stylegan2 master, you can get past these.

While the notebook has its purposes, debugging these kind of issues is better in an IDE, so I recommend setting it up, and stepping through line by line on these kind of problems, otherwise it might be difficult to see the exact kind of problem.

Comment: Thank you, I will check that.